# Razor Class Library: referencing other assembly in Page breaks Azure publish

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.1

Starting point : the [Razor Class Library (RCL) tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.1). I can publish it on Azure, and access the Razor page as expected.

Now, I'm creating another `.netstandard` library, called `MyCompany.ClassLibrary1`. It contains a single class:

```cs
namespace MyCompany.ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string Message => "This is a test";
    }
}
```

I'm referencing it in the `Page1Model` class, like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using MyCompany.ClassLibrary1;

namespace RazorClassLib.MyFeature.Pages
{
    public class Page1Model : PageModel
    {
        public string Message;

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Message = new Class1().Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, just to check that everything works properly, I use it in `Page1.cshtml`:

```html
@page
@model RazorClassLib.MyFeature.Pages.Page1Model

<html>
<body>
    OK from Razor page lib: @Model.Message
</body>
</html>
```

When launching on my machine, everything works perfectly.

However, when trying to publish the web app on Azure, the Razor page precompilation fails, with the following error:

> `Areas\MyFeature\Pages\Page1.cshtml.cs(2,7): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyCompany' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

**Questions**:

1. Why does the publish step tries to recompile the Razor pages from the RCL?
2. Why can't it find the namespace from my library?

I've created a small [GitHub](https://github.com/metoule/RCL-PublishTest) repository with all the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was simply to add a reference to the proper Razor SDK to the RCL project. For some reason, it was using an old version.

Fix : add a reference to Nuget package `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` version `2.1.1`.